# sql query help join (i think)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble figuring our how I can get results only when products.published, product_types.published, and product_cats.published = 1 but my query isn't working. Please help:

```
SELECT 
  `products`.`title`,
  `products`.`menu_id`,
  `products`.`short_description`,
  `products`.`datasheet_icon`,
  `products`.`datasheet`,
  `products`.`ordering`,
  `products`.`product_type_id`,
  CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(`products`.`alias`)
    THEN CONCAT_WS(':', `products`.`id`, `products`.`alias`) 
    ELSE `products`.`id` 
  END AS slug 
FROM 
  `products`, 
  `product_cats`,
  `product_types`
WHERE 
  `products`.published=1 AND
  `product_cats`.published=1 AND
  `product_types`.published=1 AND
  `products`.`product_cat_id`='42' AND
  `product_types`.`id` IN (1,40,48,49,50)
GROUP BY `products`.`id`
ORDER BY `product_types`.`ordering`, `products`.`ordering`
```

Comment: Can you post the error message? My first inclination is that case when char_length('products'.'alias') is missing something unless it returns a boolean.

Comment: @xQbert: pretty sure you are correct as well.  OP needs to add a condition onto the `WHEN CHAR_LENGTH` statement as `CHAR_LENGTH` appears to return an `INT`

Comment: char_length('products'.'alias') part works fine.

Comment: Based on a comment below, you're not getting an error; just no results.  Eliminate the where clause do you get results?  Start adding each line back in one at a time.  its possible no criteria match what your looking for.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to assume tables product_cats and product_types have product ids in them as well. And I call them pid in this:

```
SELECT 
    p.title,
    p.menu_id,
    p.short_description,
    p.datasheet_icon,
    p.datasheet,
    p.ordering,
    p.product_type_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(p.alias)
        THEN CONCAT_WS(':', p.id, p.alias) 
        ELSE p.id 
    END AS slug 
FROM products p
    JOIN product_cats pc ON pc.pid = p.id
    JOIN product_types pt ON pt.pid = p.id
WHERE 
    p.published=1 AND
    pc.published=1 AND
    pt.published=1
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY pt.ordering,p.ordering
```

Comment: SELECT 
    p.title,
    p.menu_id,
    p.short_description,
    p.datasheet_icon,
    p.datasheet,
    p.ordering,
    p.product_type_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(p.alias)
        THEN CONCAT_WS(':', p.id, p.alias) 
        ELSE p.id 
    END AS slug 
FROM products p
    JOIN product_cats pc ON pc.id = p.id
    JOIN product_types pt ON pt.id = p.id
WHERE 
    p.published=1 AND
    pc.published=1 AND
    pt.published=1 AND
 pt.id IN (1,40,48,49,50)
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY pt.ordering,p.ordering

Comment: The query I assumes that pid is a column in product_cats and product_types and references products.id.

Answer (score 0):

You need join tables!

```
FROM 
`products`, 
`product_cats`,
`product_types`
```

Use relational fields to do it and your problem will be gone!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your query is a bit of a mess.  Without the table structures we can only guess at what you're trying to do.  The critical information is how the three tables are related to each other.

Note the following:

1. You are using three tables in your SELECT, but are not JOINing them.  You will need to explicitly JOIN the tables you use.  The lack of explicit JOINs is the reason you're getting too many rows back and are having to use GROUP BY to eliminate duplicates.  Your final solution should not use GROUP BY.
2. If you're only searching for product.cat_id of 42, I presume you know whether than cat_id is published and you don't need to involve the product_cats table.  Is that correct?
3. Presumably there's a column `product.type_id` or something similar.  Since you are searching for a limited number of these, do you know in advance that the ids in that list are published?